# Recoil refresh state not working of that state has been altered

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I'm trying to reset my state by calling the APi to get the latest data. The API call returns an array of object.

```
export const launchesState = atom<Launch[]>({
  key: 'launchesStateLatest',
  default: selector<Launch[]>({
    key: 'launchesStateInit',
    get: async () => {
      const response = await getLaunches();
      return response.data.map(launch => ({ ...launch, isSelected: false }));
    },
  }),
});
```

I'm using a selectorFamily to select each object when the list is rendered.

```
export const launchState = selectorFamily<Launch | undefined, string>({
  key: 'launchState',
  get:
    missionName =>
    ({ get }) => {
      return get(launchesState).find(item => item.mission_name === missionName);
    },
  set:
    missionName =>
    ({ get, set }) => {
      const currentState = get(launchesState);
      const index = currentState.findIndex(item => item.mission_name === missionName);

      set(
        launchesState,
        produce(currentState, draft => {
          draft[index].isSelected = !currentState[index].isSelected;
        }),
      );
    },
});
```

The UI contains a checkbox for each item in the array and when click it uses the `set` function in the selectorFamily ti update the `launchesState`.

I'd like to refresh the data using:

```
useRecoilRefresher_UNSTABLE(launchesState)
```

Which works ok if the data has never been altered, or is reset using `useResetRecoilState(launchesState)`, but if I have clicked any of the checkboxes and altered the state then the state isn't refreshed.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening, is it a bug or is this happening for a reason?

Comment: Did you found a solution?? I have the same problem when the state is altered, the "parent" selectorFamily gets stale and returns the old state value but not the new.